Elongation before plastic deformation
As far as I understand elongation is the lengthening of a metal in % of it's initial length right before it breaks.
But what is in practice more interesting (for some aspects of my bike use case) is the amount of lengthening before it plastically deforms.
Are those two (you could call them "ultimate elongation" and "yield elongation", not sure if those are proper technical terms) directly correlated for steel and for titanium? What is the ratio of "ultimate elongation" to "yield elongation" if there is such a relationship?
I have a suspicion that what I called "yield elongation" is equal to "springback". Is that correct?

Elongation at yield and elongation at failure aren't correlated for such broad material descriptions; one could have a strong but brittle alloy in which the former parameter is notably large but the latter isn't much higher, or a ductile pure metal that yields after slight elongation but doesn't pull apart until much greater elongation.
A simple estimate of the elongation at yield is the yield stress divided by the stiffness (Young's modulus), possibly subtracting the 0.2% offset (used to define yield) to obtain a conservatively smaller value:

Yes, springback is essentially this elastic strain, which is recovered when the load is removed.

"A simple estimate of the elongation at yield is the yield stress divided by the stiffness". This is what I had come up with as well after I posted the question. Thanks for confirming it.
